# Getting the users total invites in Discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

**I am trying to add a command to my bot which replies with the total people the user has invited to the server**

My code:

```
if message.content.startswith('!invites'):
    totalInvites = message.guild.invites
    await message.channel.send("You have invited: " + totalInvites + " members to the server")
```

The bot replies with:

`You have invited: <bound method Guild.invites of <Guild id=server_id_goes_here name='my bot' shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=12>>  members to the server`

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got the right idea!

---

## on_message event usage:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!invites'):
        totalInvites = 0
        for i in await message.guild.invites():
            if i.inviter == message.author:
                totalInvites += i.uses
        await message.channel.send(f"You've invited {totalInvites}
    member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the server!")
```

---

## Command decorator usage:

```py
@bot.command()
async def invites(ctx):
    totalInvites = 0
    for i in await ctx.guild.invites():
        if i.inviter == ctx.author:
            totalInvites += i.uses
    await ctx.send(f"You've invited {totalInvites} member{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'} to the server!")
```

---

First I'm iterating through each invite in the guild, checking who created each one. If the creator of the invite matches the user that executed the command, it then adds the number of times that invite has been used, to a running total.

You don't need to include the `{'' if totalInvites == 1 else 's'}`, that's just for the odd case that they've invited 1 person (turns `member` into the plural - `members`).

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.invites`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.invites) - the code originally didn't work because I forgot this was a coroutine (had to be called `()` and `await`ed).
- [`Invite.uses`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Invite.uses)
- [`Invite.inviter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Invite.inviter)
- [`commands.command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command)
- [F-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) Python 3.6+

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply!
I have tried this code and I am receiving the following error:

for i in message.guild.invites:
TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Comment: No worries, thank you so much for the help, I marked your answer as the solution.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working! Good luck with the bot :^)