# How can I get the user ID of a member that joins a server and the member that invited them?

Tags: discord.py

I want to get the user ID of a member invited to the server and the member that invited them. I want to use this to give 1 currency point to the person that did the inviting and I also want to store the user ID of the member that joined so that if they leave and rejoin it doesn't give another point to the person that invited them.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876097/getting-the-users-total-invites-in-discord-py

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.